# android wifi p2p : peers discovery filtering

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm implementing the wifi p2P (direct wifi) in my android application, in order to share small files between clients. 
I'm following these pretty good tutorials:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html 
http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

I can now discover peers and connect to them.

I'd like to know if there is a way to filter the discovered peers. The first thing I'd like is to show only the peers who are using the same application. Indeed, currently my application show me all peers (phones, tablets, printers with direct wifi). I think it would be easier for the user to only have the compatible peers (peers also using the application).

If this work, I'd like to improve this and only show peers who ave accepted to share their files (a client can receive files or/and share their own files if he had activated it)

So, is it possible to do these types of peer filtering?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this ...

Adding Network Service Discovery (NSD) to your app allows your users to identify other devices on the local network that support the services your app requests. This is useful for a variety of peer-to-peer applications such as file sharing or multi-player gaming.

first you need to do

**1.Register Your Service on the Network**

**2.Discover Services on the Network**

**3.Connect to Services on the Network**

**4.Unregister Your Service on Application Close**

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html).

So using NSD your app will only see devices that supports the services your app requests, cool isn't it..?

I will get back to you if I come up with some intelligent logic for the second part.