# Filter peers (devices) list in Wifi Direct

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am developing android app for sharing data between two devices using Wifi Direct all is working great i am able to show peers list in my app and can transfer data between them.
my only problem is in my peer list i just want to show the devices which are using my app and will show on senders phone when they are on receiving mode.
i found related question of my problem but not useful for me.

[android wifi p2p : peers discovery filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287407/android-wifi-p2p-peers-discovery-filtering)

Here is my transfer fragment in which i am getting peers list

```
public class TransferFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener, peerListClickListener {

private static final String TAG = TransferFragment.class.getName();

private WifiP2pManager mWifiP2pManager;
private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
private List<WifiP2pDevice> mPeerList = new ArrayList<>();
private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
PeerListAdapter peerListAdapter;
LocationManager locationManager;
RecyclerView peersRecyclerView;
String provider;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            startDiscoverPeers();
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 8000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initWifiP2p();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    assert locationManager != null;
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mHandler.post(mRunnable);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

private void initWifiP2p() {

    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mWifiP2pManager = (WifiP2pManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    assert mWifiP2pManager != null;
    mChannel = mWifiP2pManager.initialize(getActivity(), getActivity().getMainLooper(), null);
    mReceiver = new WiFiDirectReceiver(mWifiP2pManager, mChannel, (MainActivity) getActivity());
    deletePersistentGroups();
}

private void deletePersistentGroups() {
    try {
        Method[] methods = WifiP2pManager.class.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().equals("deletePersistentGroup")) {
                // Delete any persistent group
                for (int netid = 0; netid < 32; netid++) {
                    method.invoke(mWifiP2pManager, mChannel, netid, null);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transfer, container, false);
    RippleBackground rippleBackground = view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    rippleBackground.startRippleAnimation();
    peersRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.peer_recyclerview);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}


private void startDiscoverPeers() {
    mWifiP2pManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.e(TAG, "discover success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Log.e(TAG, "discover failure");
        }
    });
}

public void stopDiscover() {

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
}

private void connectP2p(final WifiP2pDevice device) {

    final WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
    config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;
    config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
    config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.DISPLAY;
    mWifiP2pManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connected To " + device.deviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int errorCode) {

        }
    });
}


public void updateList(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {
    mPeerList.clear();
    mPeerList.addAll(peers.getDeviceList());//here i am getting devices list//
    showPeersList();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onPeerClicked(int position, WifiP2pDevice device) {
    connectP2p(device);
    peerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public static String getDeviceStatus(int statusCode) {
    switch (statusCode) {
        case WifiP2pDevice.CONNECTED:
            return "Connected";
        case WifiP2pDevice.INVITED:
            return "Invited";
        case WifiP2pDevice.FAILED:
            return "Failed";
        case WifiP2pDevice.AVAILABLE:
            return "Available";
        case WifiP2pDevice.UNAVAILABLE:
            return "Unavailable";
        default:
            return "Unknown";

    }
}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 101: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    //Request location updates:
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, TransferFragment.this);
                }

            }
        }

    }
}

private void showPeersList() {

    peersRecyclerView.hasFixedSize();
    peerListAdapter = new PeerListAdapter(mPeerList, getActivity(), this);
    peersRecyclerView.setAdapter(peerListAdapter);
    peersRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    peersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1));

}}
```

I want to know is there any way to filter them or i need to make some kind of service in my app.

Comment: Any luck filtering?

Comment: Yes i used NSD for this purpose

Comment: Can you elaborate, what is NSD?

Comment: Network Service Discover (NSD) visit this link this is very helpful library
https://github.com/rafakob/NsdHelper

All you have to do is register one device in this and on second device discover the service and by the service name you can filter the peers

Comment: @JohnKoz what actually you wanna do?

Comment: Perhaps explained by an example, as my app is discovering the other instances of my app on other devices, I'd like to prevent my smart TV from showing up in the list of available peers. For now I'm handing it by implementing a swipe right on the list to manually delete any peer that's not my app.

Comment: I dont know your app structure if you share your code may be i will be able to explain you more in details